# Is there a way to "branch" and combine two futures while maintaining a single-level chain of calls?

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I have a chain of calls like this:

```
return doFirst.thenCompose(a -> {
  return doSecond(a);
}).thenCompose(b -> {
  return doThird(b);
}).thenCompose(c -> {
  return doFourth(c);
});
```

Simplified, of course. Now, I need to add another call.

```
return doWithThird(b);
```

This one can happen concurrently with `doThird`, so one way I see is nesting a `thenCombine`:

```
return doFirst.thenCompose(a -> {
  return doSecond(a);
}).thenCompose(b -> {
  return doThird(b).thenCombine(doWithThird(b), (b1, b2) -> {
    return doSomethingWithTheThirds(b1, b2);
  });
}).thenCompose(c -> {
  return doFourth(c);
});
```

I'm just curious though, is there a way to do this without nesting? *i.e.* continue a single-level chain of calls?

Comment: Why do you use this `-> { return expression; }` syntax instead of just `-> expression` throughout this code? It makes half of it pure noise.

Comment: are you looking for something like [`thenComposeAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenComposeAsync(java.util.function.Function)))?

Comment: Regarding two actions chained on stage three, `thenCombine` is *not* the way to go. After all, you have changed the *fourth* stage now, which is far away of your task description of running two concurrent third stages.

Comment: @Holger - Because it's simplified from what I actually have and I wanted to keep the form instead of continuous arrows.

Comment: Well, if there’s even more code in these blocks, the readability suffers so much, that it doesn’t matter whether these calls are nested or chained. You better put this code into methods then, which will bring you back to the `-> expression` syntax (or method references). Besides that, the literal meaning of the words already says it. A single chain can not have branches.

Comment: What about [`CompletableFuture.allOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-)?

Comment: @sp00m that would still not form a linear chain of method calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept to use local variables, you can avoid the nesting of the lambda expressions/“*chain of calls*”:

```
second = doFirst.thenCompose(a -> {
  return doSecond(a);
});
third = second.thenCompose(b -> doThird(b));
otherThird = second.thenCompose(b -> doWithThird(b));
return third.thenCombine(otherThird, (b1, b2) -> {
    return doSomethingWithTheThirds(b1, b2);
  });
}).thenCompose(c -> {
  return doFourth(c);
});
```

This should also help making your code more readable since long chains of calls with long lambdas tend to lose readability.

Of course you can still inline `third` and `otherThird` if you want to reduce the number of *chains*.